# multiple out parameters with a return

Tags: c#, return, out

I have a method declaration like this:

```
public int myMethod(int x, out int y, out int z)
{
    int k;
    foreach(int i in someList)
    {
        if(anotherMethod(out k))
        {
            z = k;
        }
        else
        {
            z = 0;
        }
    }

    y = someValue;

    return anotherValue;
}
```

but I get this compiling error

> The out parameter 'z' must be assigned to before control leaves the current method

Comment: In the case `someList` is empty, `z` never gets a value.

Comment: put initalize  z  at first ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If `someList` is empty, it will never enter the `foreach` loop, and therefore `z` will never be assigned. To resolve this, ensure that `z` is given a value regardless of of the contents of `someList`:

```
public int myMethod(int x, out int y, out int z)
{
    z = 0; // or whatever default value you like

    ...
}
```

However, you should probably consider refactoring this code. It's likely there's a better way to accomplish this. If you'd really like to return 3 different `int` values, you might consider using a `Tuple<int, int, int>` or creating a custom data type to represent the value.

Answer (score 1):

**Reason : out paramaeters must be initialised before returning from the function.**

> You are assigning value for  parameter z inside if block so compiler
>   could not identify whether it can be initialized or not hence initialize
>   your parameter z before if block as below:

```
public int myMethod(int x, out int y, out int z)
{
    int k;
    z=0;
    foreach(int i in someList)
    {

        if(anotherMethod(out k))
        {
            z = k;
        }
        else
        {
            z = 0;
        }
    }

    y = someValue;

    return anotherValue;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If `someList` is empty, then `z` will never be assigned a value, which violates it's being an `out` variable. Remove the `out` constraint, or reconfigure your function logic.